# Move command in Dialog based aplications

Tags: visual-c++

I working on Dialog based applications once i right click on the Dialog Title bar a drop down list is coming with two options 1. Move and 2. Alt+F4 close. Once the User Press Move and he can able to drag the window as he desired and I add the On NC Hits Test to stop dragging its stopping normal dragging but it is not working in this particular context can any body help me in fixing this Bug.

Comment: I think you need to post code of a small example program which shows this error.

Comment: What "On NC Hits Test"? Please update your question with more precisions.

Answer (score 0):

When the user use the keyboard interface, he can move a windows with the arrow keys, without using the mouse.

If you want to limit the position of your dialog, process the [WM_MOVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632632.aspx) message.